What is the preferred pronunciation of the word "pace" when used as a preposition (meaning: "contrary to the opinion of")?
Merriam-Webster gives ˈpā-(ˌ)sē, ˈpä-(ˌ)chā, and ˈpä-(ˌ)kā . Since this preposition is not in my active vocabulary, nor have I ever heard it used, I'm wondering which pronunciation I should adopt for the rare occasion when I might need it. Its Latin derivation makes me inclined to choose the third option, the one where the "c" has the /k/ sound. But I'd like to avoid, if possible, the impression of snobbery, just as I'd like to avoid the impression of being uncultured, which the first-listed pronunciation ("pay-see") could suggest. (N.B. I realize the word belongs to elevated diction, so it's hard not to sound pretentious when using it.) Anybody out there who has personal experience with this rare preposition, either using it or hearing it used?

I don't know how this is going to be anything other than a matter of opinion. There are different schools of thought over Latin pronunciation (obviously nobody knows exactly how Latin was pronounced, but there is traditional English pronunciation as well as more modern estimates). And while you already seem to have opinions about the relative status of different pronunciations, you don't indicate whether you want to sound authentically Latin or traditional upper-class English, or what else.

Oxford Languages gives /'peɪsi,ˈpɑːtʃeɪ/ ("pay-see" or "parchay" (for non-rhotic speakers)).
